# Javascript findIndex is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have a json array:

```
[    
  {"id":19,"name":"Jed", "lastname":"DIAZ", "hobby":"photo", "birthday":"2011/11/22"},
  {"id":20,"name":"Judith", "lastname":"HENDERSON", "hobby":"pets", "birthday":"1974/06/12"},
  {"id":21,"name":"Nicolai", "lastname":"GRAHAM", "hobby":"reading", "birthday":"2005/01/22"},
  {"id":22,"name":"Vasile", "lastname":"BRYANT", "hobby":"singing", "birthday":"1987/03/17"}
]
```

function to remove a item from json array

```
 removeItem: function(removeId){
   //paramater validation
   return dataLoad.then(function(data){

     f = data.findIndex(function(item) { return item.id == removeId; });

     if(f < 0)
       return false;
     data.splice(f,1);

     LS.setData(data,"cutomers");

     return true;
   });
 }
```

When the code is running there is an error:

> findIndex is not a function

error line

```
 f = data.findIndex(function(item) { return item.id == removeId; });
```

Comment: Maybe you should update your title to the question, as the question body doesn't mention `indexof`.

Comment: Did you do a `console.log(data)` before that line? More specifically, can you confirm that `data` is an `Array`?

Comment: Could you share the whole code? There is no enough information.

Comment: Joachim Pileborg, thnx for title  :). And no i dinn`t console.log(data).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`findIndex` is not a prototype method of `Array` in [ECMASCRIPT 262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), you might need `filter` combined with `indexOf`, instead, it has the advantage of stopping searching as soon as entry is found

```
var f;
var filteredElements = data.filter(function(item, index) { f = index; return item.id == removeId; });


if (!filteredElements.length) {
    return false;
}

data.splice(f, 1);
```

---

**EDIT as suggested in comments by [Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz):**

This solution is using [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead

```
var f;
var found = data.some(function(item, index) { f = index; return item.id == removeId; });

if (!found) {
    return false;
}

data.splice(f, 1);
```

---

Found at [Array.prototype.findIndex MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

[image]

Comment: instead of filter, i would suggest `Array.prototype.some` because it stops the iteration if found.

Comment: Agreed, updating my answer accordingly

Comment: You answer gives the impression that `filter` will stop iteration when finding a match. This is not true - it is true for `some` though.

Answer (score 6):

I think you'll find your answer in your own headline; you're probably looking for indexOf, instead of findIndex. findIndex is a part of ECMAScript2015 and isn't very widely supported yet.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), findIndex is only supported in Firefox 25+ and Safari 7.1+, so if you're testing in any other browser you'd get the error you're having.

There is a suggested polyfill att the MDN page that you can use if you want to use findIndex today.

Comment: "There is a suggested polyfill att the MDN page that you can use if you want to use findIndex today." This was helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the polyfill returns the index as a string (at least in IE 11)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Polyfill as IE do **not support** Array.prototype.findIndex()

I have tested and it worked for me.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill) has a polyfill for this.

Hope this helps!

————————

Edit:

MDN has removed the polyfill section.

I would recommend to add core-js in your project for polyfills.
[Core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-array)

Comment: The page you linked to, lists it under Standard built in objects for Array

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution

make the declaration under your code with findLastIndex

```html
Array.prototype.findLastIndex = function(predicate) {
   for (let i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       if (predicate(this[i], i, this)) {
           return i; 
       } 
   } return -1; 
};
```

and it will fix your issue