# Chrome for Android actually supports Array.prototype.findIndex?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome

for some reason ,I need to use the feature of Array.prototype.findIndex ,so I just go to MDN and get some tips of that method.I went to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex and **got that Chrome for Android have no support for the feature.** I am very curious because ES6 have been released for 2 years ,and chrome for android have no reason to no support just a Array.prototype method .

I connected my desktop with my mobile phone.and used desktop chrome to debug chrome for Android. I need to avoid polyfill effect,so I just visited a not found page.

here is my test screenshot
[image: my test screenshot]

And my need to show you guys my ua:

"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; VS987 Build/NRD90U) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.125 Mobile Safari/537.36"

So finally,**Does MDN show some error tips ** ?

Comment: It's quite possible that they simply haven't gotten around to confirming that support yet. They only confirmed support for Edge on [**May 11**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex$history?page=1).

Comment: if so ,maybe should give some feedback to them.

Answer (score 0):

An accepted answer in this question: [Javascript findIndex is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32221747/javascript-findindex-is-not-a-function)  suggests using [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead

Comment: see other comment:It's quite possible that they simply haven't gotten around to confirming that support yet. They only confirmed support for Edge on

Comment: that is a better answer for me .